# Application of existence and uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1,y_2$ be solutions on $(a,b)$ to $y'''+P(x)y''+Q(x)y'+R(x)y=0,$ where $P,Q,R$ are continuous functions on $(a,b).$ Let $x_o \in (a,b).$ Suppose $y_1(x_o)=y_2(x_o)=0$ and $y'_1(x_o)y''_2(x_o)=y'_2(x_o)y''_1(x_o).$ Prove $y_2$ is multiple of $y_1$ or $y_1$ is multiple of $y_2.$

May I verify if my solution is correct? Thank you.

Proof: There exists $k_1,k_2$ (not both zero) such that $k_1y'_1(x_o)+k_2y'_2(x_o)=0$ $, k_1y''_1(x_o)+k_2y''_2(x_o)=0$ and  $k_1y_1(x_o)+k_2y_2(x_o)=0.$  Consider $\phi\equiv k_1y_1+k_2y_2.$ Then $\phi$ is a solution and satisfies same initial condition at $x_o$ as zero solution.  By existence uniqueness theorem, $k_1y_1+k_2y_2 \equiv 0.$

Comment: Your proof is correct.